# reducing(or stopping)the pop when a speaker is switched

Tags: arduino, mosfet, amplifier, audio

Is it possible to stop or reduce the popping sound which is emitted from the speaker when you turn on and off an amplifier? i am using a [PAM8403](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8403.pdf) connected to a 4ohm speaker. i am switching using a low side mosfet connected to an arduino. Thanks.

Comment: Don't have a DC component to your signal anywhere helps as a start.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132344/circuits-in-audio-amplifiers-to-protect-speakers

Comment: For one thing, don't do low-side switching on your amplifier. That practically guarantees a full-voltage transient on power-on/off.

Comment: You do know that thing has a deep sleep inhibit at <1uA right. Not sure why you would want to cut it's power...

Comment: @DaveTweed This would require a P channel mosfet no? I am currently using an N channel as i have it in my head that P channel are more difficult to switch. forgive my ignorance, i am new to transistor switching outside of an arduino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MUTE or SHDN inputs of the PAM8403 (pin 5 or 12) with your arduino instead of switching with a MOSFET. Popping sound will be greatly reduced. Also, put an high pass filter on the inputs as shown in the datasheet. Its cutoff frequency should match your speakers' bandwidth.

Comment: im using one of these broken out boards [link](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Tiny-Mini-PAM8403-Module-5V-2-x-3W-Output-Digital-Audio-Amplifier-Stereo-USB-Amp/191990012293?epid=693718398&hash=item2cb37f1985:g:-d0AAOSwpLNX9~-U) would this still need the high pass filter? I will experiment with the pins you suggest. I thought it would be simpler to just switch it on and off with a mosfet as i am also switching an mp3 module at the same time.