# removing the pop noise when amp is switched with passive components only

Tags: amplifier, speakers

I've recently bought [this little 2*3W USB-powered amp](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/MP3-Mini-Drive-by-Wire-8403-USB-Audio-Amplifier-Board-5V-2-3W-volume-control-3/32617680542.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.6c4c4c4dyemsLU) and it is working pretty well with my old Panasonic boombox speakers (rated 2.7 ohms, 15w peak input).

However when switching off the USB power i hear a "pop" noise from the speakers.

I've seen there are [pop-suppression circuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132344/circuits-in-audio-amplifiers-to-protect-speakers) to avoid that, but i'd like to go with a passive solution not requiring any extra power.

So can i just wire 2 [slide switches like these](https://www.pololu.com/product/1408) in series with the speakers and manually flip them before turning off the amp?

Are the switches better wired on the positive or negative side of the speakers?

Comment: UPDATE: [circuit built and amp mini review](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/wordpress/archives/80).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu1f8G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simplified schematic of amplifier output and proposed switching arrangement.*

The "pop" occurs because the amplifier is running on a single-ended supply. To provide drive for positive and negative excursions of the speaker the amplifier is biased to half-supply when quiet, so, on a 12 V amplifier you would expect to find 6 V on the left side of C1. On power-up the left side of C1 jumps up by 6 V and this is passed through to the speaker. On power-down the opposite happens.

> So can i just wire 2 slide switches like these in series with the speakers and manually flip them before turning off the amp?

Yes. Be aware that 15 W in to 2.5 Ω will give \$ I = \sqrt {\frac P R } = \sqrt {\frac {15}{2.5}} = 2.4 \text A \$. Your switches are rated at 0.3 A.

> Are the switches better wired on the positive or negative side of the speakers?

It doesn't matter which wire is cut.

I've added R1 so that on power-up C1 can discharge before you close the switch.

Comment: The amp is only 3W per channel. The speakers were rated 15W.

Comment: Yup, but that information wasn't in the question when I answered. I'll leave the re-calculation as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: can i omit C1 and the resistor R1 going to ground? i'd like to keep it as simple as possible...

Comment: C1 is in the amplifier already. If it wasn't you would have DC running through your speaker. Yes, you can leave out R1 but you can expect a pop on switch on.

Answer (score 0):

Click and pop suppression is a standard feature in an amp driver these days.

Since the amp you have doesn’t handle it properly, consider a different amp. That would be less work than trying to retrofit this one.